# Как в react native обратиться к элементу без классов

Tags: react-native, expo

В react native чтобы обратиться к элементу текущему, например к Text посредством вызова onClick можно было указать this и таким образом выполнить функцию к текущему элементу. Это когда элементов одинаковых много и надо кликнуть на каком-то и сделать именно с ним что-то. Но как это сделать если я использую функции и хуки? Вроде есть useRef, правильно я понимаю? И его как-то можно использовать в этом случае?

Например есть два компонента Text в View контейнере. У Text я использую событие onClick и мне надо сделать так, чтобы при клике менялся backgroundColor именно этого Text, на котором я кликнул.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.